# How can I declare a variable in Pyomo as a matrix?

Tags: python, pyomo

I'm trying to this:

```
P_sell = np.array([mod.addVar(lb=0, ub=gen_Max[g], name="exchanges_sell") for g in range(n_gen) for l in range(n_load)]).reshape((n_gen,n_load))
```

but I'm using Pyomo, so I think can't declare the variable directly into "model" because it's a matrix so I did this:

```
def sell(model, gen):
     return (0, model.capmax_act[gen])
model.venda= Var(model.gen, bounds=sell, doc='P sell')

p_sell = np.array([model.venda[gen] for gen in model.gen for loads in model.loads]).reshape((n_gen,n_load))
```

where model.capmax_act[gen] is the same as gen_Max[g]

Does it represent the same thing? Or is it possible to declare model.p_sell as a matrix of variables instead of doing this?

I'm kind of new to python, but I hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the first part of your question comes from the Gurobi-Python interface correct?

If I understand correctly, the `model.gen` and `model.loads` are Pyomo Sets in your code. Then, first, I would define the `model.capmax_act` as a Pyomo parameter, which is indexed by `model.gen` and `model.loads`:

```
model.capmax_act = Param(model.gen, model.loads, initialize = 100) # You can replace "100" with any structure that Pyomo accepts to initialize model parameters.
```

Then your `p_sell` variable can be defined as:

```
p_sell = Var(model.gen, model.loads, lb=0, ub=model.capmax_act)
```